# Carrierwave temp directory set to uploads/tmp folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I started using Carrierwave, and I found out that it stores temporary files at multiple places depending on whether it is testing or delayed job.

If it is done during testing(rspec), the temp files will be at `RAILS_ROOT/uploads/tmp` directory.

If it is done during delayed job, the temp files will be at `RAILS_ROOT/public/uploads/tmp`

First, I was thinking that `rails_root/tmp/uploads` would be a more sensible place, or even the system temporary folder.

Second, the testing being different to normal run seems like a bug.

Is there a way to fix this (either by configuration or monkey patching)? And can I put things in the RAILS_ROOT/tmp folder?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is `config.cache_dir` option you can set in 'config/initializers/carrierwave.rb'. But it is relative to '/public'. Looks like you should do that in your uploaders:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def cache_dir
    # should return path to cache dir
    Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads'
  end
end
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Note that you will need to restart your application for this to take affect.

Comment: I also added `attr_writer cache_dir` to the class and changed the function to `@cache_dir || Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads'` to allow per-instance overrides (useful for isolating test files from development files).

Comment: What is the difference between cache_dir and store_dir?

Comment: Is the cache_dir used in tests and store_dir in development/production?

Answer (score 7):

Im using carrierwave 0.10.0 and It seems this behaviour was addressed. Now the `cache_dir` setting accepts a path that is outside the public directory:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

@iKindred's answer worked for me, but I thought I'd expand on how I got it to work on Rails 4.2.3 with CarrierWave 0.10.0:

**Where to put the configure block**

As CarrierWave is not part of Rails, the best place to put the configure block, according to my reading of the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files), is an initializer file.  The name can be chosen arbitrarily, but it needs to reside in `Rails.root/config/initializers`.  I chose to name the file after the module I was configuring: `Rails.root/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb`.

**What to put in the initializer file**

I find that I run tests while my Rails app is running in `development` mode.  After the tests I clean up all files by unlinking the storage paths as described [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Cleanup-after-your-Rspec-tests). For that to work without messing with the files stored by the Rails app running in `development` mode, storage paths need to be separated by environment!  Therefore, my modified version of @iKindred's answer is:

```
#config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'uploads', Rails.env)
end
```